# sqlite concurrency bulk insert

Tags: php, sqlite, gearman

I read sqlLite is better for SELECT rather than for insert
and especially for concurrency insert because locks the entire database file
but I would like to know your last point :).

So I'm wondering if I get myself into troubles
with such a thing:

```
foreach($rows as $row){
    if(null === $model->check($row->id,$row->name)){
        //prepare date
        $model->insert($data);
    }
}
```

the code is inside a gearman worker so I've
more than one instance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From my experience with SQLite, yes this will cause problems. UPDATEs and INSERTs in loops have a high failure rate because of the locking, at least in my previous experiences.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do you know if there are problems with bulk delete ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also want to look at [Berkeley DB](http://bit.ly/gYaDfo). The [SQL API](http://bit.ly/g06gVO) for Berkeley DB is SQLite compatible, but it has much higher concurrency because it doesn't require exclusive database write locks. Because the API is SQLite compatible, it's an easy test to rebuild your application against the Berkeley DB library.

Answer (score 1):

No problem at all to me.
Here's a great **read** regarding sqlite locks: http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html